# How to debug Apache issue or upgrade Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, debugging, upgrade

Something (dunno what, perhaps GIT which I just upgraded) is causing my connection to loalhost to work veeeery slowly.

Using WinXP Pro.

I was thinking to upgrade Apache, but could not figure out how to upgrade.
The installer warns me that I should first uninstall the existing server, which I don't want to do.

If I ignore that warning, will it overwrite my htdocs folder? My .conf settings? The connection to PHP / MySQL?

Is there some easy way to do this? Command line is OK, but be descriptive please; assume that I am a noob.

Is there a different way to see what is interfering with Apache?

EDIT - A better description:

There are no obvious extraneous or heavy processes running [checked using Sysinternals Process Explorer]

The server/PHP/MySQL all seem to be running fine - OffByOne is able to immediately retrieve a correctly generated page (it just can't render it, being OffByOne).

The other browsers [IE/FF/Webkits] have no problem with short pages [under 5 lines], even with server requests included. Generated pages such as phpinfo() also display fine.

But longer pages [25 lines] - even of plain static HTML - take 15 minutes or more to load in the regular browsers.

It was my hope that some default path or something was overwritten, and that the upgrade would re-overwrite it back to how it was. Not professional, but the closest I could think to rebooting for such an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading some random component when something else caused things to break (that is, Apache to slow down) is likely not the best approach for fixing it.

Perhaps first try to see from Task Manager (ctrl+alt+del) if there are some weird processes taking lots of resources. Find out whether it's Apache or MySQL that's slow: try some static pages via localhost - are they slow too? And so on. Try to find the root cause of the problem instead of just installing something and hoping it to magically fix it.

Comment: A better description of the issue has been added to the question.  I agree that the methodology is wanting.

Answer (score 0):

you should save all your config file somewhere, uninstall your X/Wamp and reinstall it and copy back your configuration file.

Also make sure to dump all your mysql database, reimporting with some `SQL` script is really more easy.

Comment: I have very many gigabytes on the server, backing up and restoring is no trivial matter. I keep a running backup [Backblaze], and almost everything is committed either with HG or GIT, but those are only if things truly do head south.